# Pandas boolean condition from nested list of dictionaries

Tags: pandas, list, dictionary, nested-lists

```
 [{'id': 123,
  'type': 'salary', #Parent node
  'tx': 'house',
  'sector': 'EU',
  'transition': [{'id': 'hash', #Child node
    'id': 123,
    'type': 'salary',
    'tx': 'house' }]},
 {'userid': 123,
  'type': 'salary', #Parent node
  'tx': 'office',
  'transition': [{'id': 'hash', # Child node
    'id': 123,
    'type': 'salary',
    'tx': 'office'}]}]
```

As a pandas column (`'info'`) I have some information stored as a nested list of dictionaries like the example above.

What I'm trying to do is a boolean condition whether this list has the following attributes:

1. More than one `'type' == 'salary'` in any of all parents nodes
2. Field `'tx'` is different in any of all parents nodes with `'type' == 'salary'`

So far I've tried to flatten a list and filter but it is not solving the first and seconds nodes

```
a = df.iloc[0].info
values = [item for sublist in [[list(i.values()) for i in a]][0]for item in sublist]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to one line solution, you can use:

```
df['check'] = df['info'].apply(lambda x: True if sum([1 if i['type']=='salary' else 0 for i in x]) > 1 and [i['tx'] for i in x if i['type']=='salary'].count([i['tx'] for i in x if i['type']=='salary'][0]) != len([i['tx'] for i in x if i['type']=='salary'])  else False)
```

or (expanded):

```
def check(x):
    total_salary = sum([1 if i['type']=='salary' else 0 for i in x]) # get count of "type": "salary" matches
    tx_list = [i['tx'] for i in x if i['type']=='salary'] # get tx values when type==salary
    tx_check = tx_list.count(tx_list[0]) != len(tx_list) # check all values are same in tx_list
    if total_salary > 1 and tx_check:
        return True
    else:
        return False
df['check'] = df['info'].apply(check)
```

Comment: Hi! thanks so much for your answer. Just edited one condition `'tx'` is different in any of all parents nodes with `'type == salary'`. Apologies for this late change